# OnTriggerStay2D is not working. No compiler errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to "isCarDrafting" to be true whenever I enter a box collider with a tag "Draft". There are no compiler errors but when I enter the box collider nothing happens. It is worth noting that the box colliders with the "Draft" tags are child objects of another moving objects. I suspect this might have something to do with my problem, but even if my suspicions were true, I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

```
public bool isCarDrafting;

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D colDraft)
{   
    if (colDraft.tag == "Draft")
    {
        isCarDrafting = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isCarDrafting = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the function to check if it gets executed?  I suspect you are missing the rigidbody2d or collider component on your car object, or the tag is incorrect on the draft object.

Comment: Also, seems like this can be simplified to OnTriggerEnter2D and OnTriggerExit2D.  OnTriggerStay2D will fire every physics frame afaik, which is good when doing ongoing calculations, but for toggling a boolean, those extra events are useless.

Comment: Thanks alot, its the second time i forgot about the rigidbody.

Comment: Happy to help.  I posted an answer with a checklist of things to run through when facing issues with OnTrigger and OnCollision functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with errors in the `OnTrigger` and `OnCollision` methods, the usual suspects are:

1. Missing Rigidbody Component
2. Missing Collider Component
3. Collider is marked as IsTrigger for collision
4. Collider is not marked as IsTrigger for trigger
5. Script is on the wrong object or missing completely

Since you are dealing with `tags`, an additional suspect is a misnamed tag.

If you are positive everything in the scene is setup correctly, the next step is logging.  Check if the function is firing by placing a log at the very top of the function, outside of any other code blocks.  Sometimes the function is firing correctly, but an incorrect comparison is stopping the intending functionality.